# How to test humidity or temperature sensors via Emulator?

Tags: android, android-sensors

Is it possible to test new sensors like humidity or temperature using Android emulator? Official one or any alternative one.

There is so little information on this on official website, even on Stackoverlow. I guess it's not possible, but I rather asked to be absolutely sure.

Comment: I guess your guess is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to **fake some data**, but you'll have to do some command-line foo!

In the emulator you could fake some temperature & humidity values you just have to connect to your emulator via **telnet**.

1. Connect to emulator. Open a terminal and type (5554 is the number of the first emulator):

   `telnet localhost 5554`
2. list status of all sensors and see if temperature is enabled:

   `sensor status`
3. Set some fake values (set whatever you want. Don't worry your emulator won't melt if you set crazy values):

   `sensor set temperature 1:2:3`
4. Check the values that have been set as temperature:

   `sensor get temperature`

==> you can change those settings at the same time your app is running in the emulator! so just set different temperature values and see what happens in your app. I didn't develop a temperature sensor app yet, but I know that telnet works great for faking geolocation data during testing my location based apps. I don't see any reason why it should not work for temperatures as well.

BTW: if you are getting lost in telnet you can always type `help` or `help <command>` to get some additional infos

Comment: Just saw the message, it's morning here :). Anyway, I am still not in the phase where I can test this in my own app. I will try to install another temperature app and test this. Any time it be right answer, I will accept this as an answer ;). Upvote for the idea!

Comment: Ok, let me know once you have tested this :-)

Comment: Temperature works. What is the command for humidity? `sensor set humidity`?

Comment: Actually, `sensor status` does not show existence of humidity sensor in the emulator?

Comment: I could not find a humidity sensor either. Maybe it is currently only possible with temperature. Humidity Sensor was added later to android. I fear it is not yet supported in emulator, but I am not sure about that.